# How do I hover on Browser's cancel button?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to populate a splash screen on my website and it is populating if scroll pos is between 1-120, using following JS code.

Please suggest what should be done if I want to execute this on hover browser's and tab's cancel button?

How to read that, cause `$(window).scrollTop();` won't return anything if it is less that 0.

```
      function setHeightToEmergencyContainer () {
        var getWindowHeight = $(window).height();
        var setHeight = (getWindowHeight - 123)/2;
    }
    setHeightToEmergencyContainer();
    $(window).resize(function() {
        setHeightToEmergencyContainer();
    });
    function addEvent(obj, evt, fn) {
        if (obj.addEventListener) {
            obj.addEventListener(evt, fn, false);
        }
        else if (obj.attachEvent) {
            obj.attachEvent("on" + evt, fn);
        }
    }
    addEvent(window,"load",function(e) {
        addEvent(document, "mouseout", function(e) {
            e = e ? e : window.event;
            var from = e.relatedTarget || e.toElement;
            if (!from || from.nodeName == "HTML") {
                // stop your drag event here
                // for now we can just use an alert
                setHeightToEmergencyContainer();
                var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
                console.log("scroll pos :: "+scroll);
                if(scroll > 0 && scroll <= 120){
                    console.log("show popup "+scroll);

                    $(".tso_pop-container").css({"width":"1366px","height":"700px","overflow":"auto","right":"-296px","top":"106px"});
                }
                //$.cookie("dontShowUrgencyContainer","yes");

            }
        });
        addEvent(document, "mouseover", function() {
            $(".tso_pop-container").css({"width":"0px","height":"0px","overflow":"hidden","right":"50%","top":"50%"});
        });
    });

//}

window.onblur = function(event) {
    $(".tso_pop-container").css({"width":"0px","height":"0px","overflow":"hidden","right":"50%","top":"50%"});
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

first to get scrolled position of document use :

```
$('body').scrollTop() // webkit
$('html').scrollTop() // moz
```

for browser hover use :

```
$(window).mouseenter(function(){
   var stop = $('html').scrollTop() == 0 ? $('body').scrollTop() : $('html').scrollTop()
   if(stop <= 120){
      // your code
   }
});
```

hope this helps you.